# Pandas df.index.round('D') for 24hr time

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe with 24hr datetime as index, rounding the datetime as days seems to increment the 'day' after 1200 hrs.

Here's a modified code-snippet from another example that generates random numbers.

Please note the output datetime index 'day' compared to the rounded 'day'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(1), freq='H')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': days, 'col2': data})
df = df.set_index('test')

df['datetime_rounded']  = df.index.round('D')
print(df)
...
2018-10-12 10:19:29.907421    43       2018-10-12
2018-10-12 11:19:29.907421    77       2018-10-12
2018-10-12 12:19:29.907421    95       2018-10-13
2018-10-12 13:19:29.907421    79       2018-10-13
```

How can I ensure that the rounded 'day' ends at the end of the Datetime index 'day'?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected, `round` function round to nearest day, so after `12:00:00` it return next day.

I think you want [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) or [`DatetimeIndex.ceil`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.ceil.html):

```
df['datetime_round']  = df.index.round('d')
df['datetime_floor']  = df.index.floor('d')
df['datetime_ceil']  = df.index.ceil('d')
print(df)
                            col2 datetime_round datetime_floor datetime_ceil
test                                                                        
2018-10-11 10:39:32.233426    29     2018-10-11     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 11:39:32.233426    56     2018-10-11     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 12:39:32.233426    82     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 13:39:32.233426    13     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 14:39:32.233426    35     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 15:39:32.233426    53     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 16:39:32.233426    25     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 17:39:32.233426    23     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 18:39:32.233426    21     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 19:39:32.233426    12     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 20:39:32.233426    15     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 21:39:32.233426     9     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 22:39:32.233426    13     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-11 23:39:32.233426    87     2018-10-12     2018-10-11    2018-10-12
2018-10-12 00:39:32.233426     9     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
2018-10-12 01:39:32.233426    63     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
2018-10-12 02:39:32.233426    62     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
2018-10-12 03:39:32.233426    52     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
2018-10-12 04:39:32.233426    43     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
2018-10-12 05:39:32.233426    77     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
2018-10-12 06:39:32.233426    95     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
2018-10-12 07:39:32.233426    79     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
2018-10-12 08:39:32.233426    77     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
2018-10-12 09:39:32.233426     5     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
2018-10-12 10:39:32.233426    78     2018-10-12     2018-10-12    2018-10-13
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, that's exactly what I needed!